# Ошибка при компиляции C4430

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

template<typename Type>
struct MiddleBuffer
{
    Type* S = nullptr;
    int S_size = 0;
    free()
    {
        delete[] S;
    }

};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

При попытке компиляции ошибка

```
C4430  missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

Но когда я убираю функцию `free()` полность, то всё в порядке, почему?

Comment: Почти прямым текстом написано. "[возвращаемый] тип пропущен"

Comment: Какой возвращаемый тип у вашей `free()`? Может, ст*о*ит написать `void free()`?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь объявить метод `free` в структуре `MiddleBuffer` без указания типа возвращаемого значения, что запрещено, на что и жалуется компилятор.
Так как ваш метод не возвращает никакого значения, необходимо указать void в качестве типа возвращаемого значения:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

template<typename Type>
struct MiddleBuffer
{
    Type* S = nullptr;
    int S_size = 0;
    void free()
    {
        delete[] S;
    }

};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```